# Why is bash setting "???" to "lib"?

Tags: bash

Please observe the following:

```
[user@machine deploy]$ echo ?
?
[user@machine deploy]$ echo ??
??
[user@machine deploy]$ echo ???
lib
[user@machine deploy]$ echo ????
????
```

What is up with `echo ???`?  Why is that "lib"?

I am not seeing anything in my env or .bashrc, and it is not consistent between machines (on my dev machine, the string ??? stayed ???, which was useful where I was testing for it).

I can work around this no problems- the "???" as a placeholder value was completely arbitrary.  But now I am curious.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In shell [globs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), `?` stands for one character (exactly - one and only one). So if you have a file (or directory) that has a name with exactly three chars, `???` will match it.

Try `touch a; touch bb ; echo ? ??`.

If you don't have a file that matches the pattern, the pattern is printed as is, with not replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: try `ls`
Hint #2: this is called globbing.